# How can I hide a dashboard menu item for non-admin users

Tags: wordpress, hide, menuitem

I have a custom plugin made, but I want this only to be visible for admins.
I figured this one out:

function remove_by_caps_admin_menu() {

```
if (is_admin() ) {
    }else{
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=registered_email' );}}
```

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_by_caps_admin_menu', 999);

this hides the menu-item for admin users.
but want to display it to admin users ONLY.

````
    
    if (!is_admin() ) {
        }else{
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=registered_email' );
}
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_by_caps_admin_menu', 999);```

this doesn't work when I login as an author.
````

Answer (score 0):

This will fix -

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_by_caps_admin_menu');

function remove_by_caps_admin_menu(){
    if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ){
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=registered_email' );
    }
}
```